# Voronoi Diagram (Delunay Triangulation) in inkscape not working properly

Tags: inkscape, svg

I'm working on a low poly face in  Inkscape 1.2.2.
But when I use the Voronoi diagram (Delaunay  triangulation) I got this ugly result :

[image: Voronoi diagram]

[image: dot image]

There are no duplicate dots.
How can I make this cleaner ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Voronoi Diagram extension is working, but it can fail for several reasons. It can be a tricky extension to use and just one misstep can lead to failure. As to which is the actual cause here, I can't tell from a screenshot alone.

Anyway, you generally need to be much more careful in your placement of dots, especially those around the nose area where you have too many at the base of the nose, and none at all at the sides further up. This will lead to a poor result. Also you need to avoid all duplicate dots. Even one duplicate will cause the extension to fail. Also when selecting your dots before running the extension you must make sure you don't select the raster image.

What follows isn't a tutorial, just the basic steps to get a good result and avoid any problems. The example below was made fairly quickly to show how this could be achieved, but you may want to take more time and add more dots to make the polygons smaller, allowing for more detail.

1. Drop a guide in the middle of the face.
2. Place your dots like this (see figure A below) for one half of the face only. Colour the ones that are on the centre line a different colour so you can see them easily.  Use snapping to Bounding Box, Edge Middle, to get them exactly on the centre line guide.
3. Copy and paste all the dots and reflect everything to the other side (as in figure B below). Use snapping to get the green dots to line up exactly.  This will make the design fully symmetrical.
4. Delete the duplicate green dots. This is vitally important here because even one duplicate will make the Voronoi Diagram extension fail.
5. Select all the dots making sure that you **don't** select the raster image, and run the extension (see result in figure C below)

[image]Click to enlarge

Comment: Thank you, @Billy Kerr for helping the OP with their problem. Please note that your first sentence suggests that the root cause was entirely with the user, but even their point cloud should have a valid Delaunay triangulation and the screenshot suggests that the software was not able to find it. Please consider rephrasing.

Comment: @KrisVanBael - that was not my intention, however I have reworded it and added more details to the introductory paragraphs to clarify.